# ASP.NET Tags not Being Converted

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrol

I am using ASP.NET tags in my markup an ASCX file.

```
<a id="MyId" runat="server" href="page.aspx?id=<%= Item.Id %>">View Item</a>
```

Item is a property in my control class in code behind.

However, the markup above is being rendered to the HTML unchanged, include the `<%= %>` characters.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `runat="server"` attribute from the anchor, like so:

```
<a href="<%= string.Format("{0}?id={1}", ResolveUrl("~/page.aspx"), item.Id) %>">
    View Item
</a>
```

or use a HyperLink:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/page.aspx?id={0}">
    View Item
</asp:HyperLink>
```

and in the code behind set the value:

```
link.NavigateUrl = string.Format(link.NavigateUrl, item.Id);
```

or using data binding syntax:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/page.aspx?id={0}", item.Id) %>'>
    View Item
</asp:HyperLink>
```

and in the code behind call:

```
Page.DataBind();
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like that's it. Makes sense I guess, since the entire tag was being processed by ASP.NET. But this really surprised me. Thanks.